# Entity Framework Attach not updating DB

Tags: database, entity-framework

I have the following problem: when i try to change the town of a user by passing the modified user entry to my ModifyUser method in my  UserService class everything seems ok but the changes are not applied in the database.

I tried the solutions from similar problems i found on stackoverflow but none of them seem to work.

As they say "a picture is worth a thousand words" take a look at this, since its easier to understand compared to my short explanation.
http://prntscr.com/el51z0

```
        else if (property == "BornTown")
        {
            if (this.townService.TownExists(value))
            {
                User user = this.userService.GetUserByName(username);

                Town town = this.townService.GetTownByName(value);
                user.BornTown = town;

                this.userService.ModifyUser(user);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Value {value} is not valid.");
                throw new ArgumentException($"Town {value} not found!");
            }
        }
```

When i pass the user to the ModifyUser the database does not update, and BornTown stays NULL.

```
    public void ModifyUser(User user)
    {
        using (PhotoShareContext context = new PhotoShareContext())
        {
            context.Users.Attach(user);

            context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to attach the town of your user ?

Comment: yes, and still no changes http://prntscr.com/el59hz

Comment: Do you have proxygeneration enabled? Do you have the FK-s also included in your model? If so, what happens if you try to update both the association and the FK in the user entity?

Comment: I am still new ti entity framework so i am not sure about the proxy thing but about the FK, the is no TownID in the user model that navigates to the town. Only a virtual Town BornTown property.

Comment: I think the problem is that in EF, an association is represented internally by its own 'entity' (they are called independent associations). You attach the user, and set its state to Modified, but this only affects that specific user object, not the internal 'user-to-town' association. Can you maybe add the TownID into the user just to check whether it makes a difference if you set that too?

Comment: there already is a FK in the table created by EF =/ http://prntscr.com/el6m4q

Comment: Not in the db. Add it to your user class. Check out this example: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/entity-framework/9413/mapping-relationship-with-entity-framework-code-first-one-to-many-and-many-to-m/29160/mapping-one-to-many#t=20170317175626719013

This helps you set up a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/el73qt does not work and also i can't rly change the models since its an exercise and i need to make do with that i got. =/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
context.Users.where(x=>x.username == username).FirstOrDefault();
```

and don't use `any()`

Can you check if you are getting the proper username, by again checking the username once you are getting back the value in the function.

Comment: Sometimes .Any() gives issues

Comment: All of those things work fine, the data is always correct and the user always exist. If i understand correctly this is what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

Or else try below code:

```
User user  = context.users.where(x=>x.username == username).FirstOrDefault();
user.BornTown = town; //string
context.savechanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manipulating the navigation properties directly try to manage the entity relation using it's foreign keys:

`Town town = this.townService.GetTownByName(value);
 user.BornTownId = town.Id;`

Keep in mind that if you have **not** created explicit foreign keys in your model entity you should map the existing one: take a look at "Users" table - see how the foreign key column is named- it should look something like `UserTown_Id`. Then put it in your model class (you may add foreign key attribute or map it in model builder).

Be careful when adding the new property to your model (it can make your optional relation with "Towns" required).